# My Ubuntu keep losing internet, even it's connected

Tags: networking, wireless, internet

I do not know how to track my problem. For example while watching video on the internet suddenly it start buffering and when I try to go to any other website, loading that page never finishes. I have to manually disconnect and reconnect to internet to make it work again. I have to say that when this happens, all other devices that are connected to the internet through same router works perfectly fine.

I am using an older version of Ubuntu (16.04) and I am talking about wireless connection.

Comment: Brand and model of your wifi adapter? Are you using external repositories like PPAs and which ones? Are you using propriatery drivers and which ones?

Comment: Also, if you connect via Ethernet, is the connection stable?